# different between loop termination assignments

Tags: loops, for-loop

what is the difference between the following 2 loops

```
for(int i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++)
    //do something

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    //do something
```

does the loop calculate the array length each iteration in the second loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form only evaluates the expression `array.length` once, and remembers it in an extra local variable (`n`). In most languages I've worked with, finding the length of an array is incredibly quick anyway, so the latter form is preferred.

Comment: so modern compilers don't cache this value in their code optimization phase?

Comment: @Akram: It *entirely* depends on the language and implementation. For Java and C# for example, the source code compiler wouldn't do much but the JIT compiler may well optimize it *if* it can determine that the value of `array` doesn't change in the loop body (and can't be changed by another thread). Without specifying the platform precisely, your question is too broad to be answered precisely.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the language and data structure we are dealing with here. It looks like array.length is a member variable and as such it is simply being returned and not calculated but it could be a property and hence could be, but probably isn't, re-calculated each time.